How to correctly use and parse an XCom list of dicts in Airflow
I am writing an Airflow dag which generates a dict list based on run parameters that I pass in json format using UI and then parses and uses its elements inside a KubernetesPodOperator. In the below code I simplified my use case to simple echo.
This is my code
from datetime import datetime

import yaml
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.pod import KubernetesPodOperator

config = yaml.safe_load(open('/opt/airflow/${dag_config_filename}', 'r'))
namespace = config['kubernetes']['namespace']

files = config['sftp']['files']  # list of 4 names

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': config['alerting_email'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'executor_config': {
        'KubernetesExecutor': {
            'service_account_name': '${airflow_worker}',
            'namespace': f'{namespace}',
        }
    },
}

execution_date = '{{ ds_nodash  }}'
wizaly_files_date_ingestion = '{{ dag_run.start_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") }}'


@dag(
    dag_id=config['dag_id'],
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Pipeline for Perfmarket ETL',
    tags=['perfmarket'],
    schedule_interval=config['schedule_interval'],
    start_date=datetime(2024, 10, 22),
    catchup=False,
    params={
        'entry_param': Param(
            default='0',
            type='string',
            enum=['0', '1', '2'],
            description='Run type: 0=daily, 1=rattrapage, 2=explo'
        )
    }
)
def test_dag() -> None:
    start_task = EmptyOperator(task_id='start')

    @task
    def define_run_confs(**context):
        params = context['params']
        entry_param = params['entry_param']
        if entry_param == '0':  # daily (default)
            files_typed = [file + '_option1' for file in config['sftp']['files']]
        elif entry_param == '1':
            files_typed = [file + '_option2' for file in config['sftp']['files']]
        else:
            files_typed = [file + '_option3' for file in config['sftp']['files']]
        zip_files = [
            {
                'first_key': f'{file_typed}.zip',
                'second_key': 'ch1' if '_type1' in file else 'ch2',
                'task_id': f'import_{file}',
            }
            for file, file_typed in zip(files, files_typed)
        ]
        return zip_files

    configs = define_run_confs() # execution of the aboce function to generate my dict list.

    import_zip_tasks = []

    # I parse my dict list and for each dict I print keys
    for file_info in configs:
        import_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
            task_id=f'import_zip_{file_info["task_id"]}',
            name='import_zip',
            cmds=['bash', '-cx'],
            arguments=[
                f"""echo {file_info['first_key']};
                echo {file_info['second_key']} \
                """
            ]
        )
        import_zip_tasks.append(import_task)

    end_task = EmptyOperator(task_id='end')

    start_task >> configs >> import_zip_tasks >> end_task


test_dag()

Problem is I am unable to parse my list because of: TypeError: 'XComArg' object is not iterable
Code seems unable to parse configs variable. How can I transform it into a normal list variable ?
I tried multiple techniques but I am unable to parse the list.
